How are the inputs fed into the decoder-only transformers during inference?
In decoder-only transformers for token prediction, I understand that during training, a whole sequence can be fed into the transformer and processes though layers. But during inference (when we want to do generate tokens), what exactly are fed into the tranformers? For example, in the first time, the token is fed, but what about other subsequent positions? Do we pad them with some special token, say, 0?

